# Theme customizer - can't add section/settings

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I'm trying to modify the WordPress theme customizer by adding sections and settings but no matter what I add in my `functions.php` file, nothing ever shows up in the customizer.

Here is my code:-

```
function starter_customize_register( $wp_customize ) 
{
    $wp_customize->add_panel( 'home_page_settings', array(
        'title' => __( 'Home Page Settings', 'starter'),
        'priority' => 10,
        'active_callback' => 'is_front_page'
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'home_call_to_action_section' , array(
        'title' => __('Call To Action','starter'),
        'panel' => 'home_page_settings',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'home_call_to_action_setting_section', array(
        'default'        => __('WHAT IS RO PURIFIER?', 'starter'),
        'sanitize_callback' => 'starter_sanitize',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('cta_heading', array(
        'label' => __('CTA Heading','starter'),
        'section' => 'home_call_to_action_section',
        'setting'=>'home_call_to_action_setting_section'

    ));    
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'starter_customize_register');
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Your use of [`add_control`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference%5CWP_Customize_Manager%5Cadd_control) is incorrect. More specifically, you are not telling what type of control you want to add. Refer to the codex link to see which types can be generated automatically. I've given an example with a text field below.

```
$wp_customize->add_control('cta_heading', array(
    'label' => __('CTA Heading','starter'),
    'section' => 'home_call_to_action_section',
    'setting'=>'home_call_to_action_setting_section',
    'type'=>'text',
));
```

Beware that if you want more complex controls, such as colours, you need to explicitly create the control object. An example is given in the codex link as well.

Comment: I have added type but still no luck..